# How to add Contrast .NET Core Site Extension in to Webapp by Azure ARM Template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I have a task to add an extension to Webapp as in the picture below, but I want it will be auto-add, I found it can't not auto by CI/CD but I will be running on Azure ARM Template, so I viewed the template of a web app and see the config Extensions, Can I put that config to Azure ARM Template when we deploy? Because another team will handle deploying Azure ARM Template so I need to make sure about technical before requesting them to do that.
[image]

[image]

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use the below `ARM template` to Install `Contrast .NET Core Site Extension` in to Webapp

Thanks @Mark LaCasse for the ARM Template code.

```cs
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "sites_name": {
      "defaultValue": "harshitha2Oct22",
      "type": "String"
    }
  },
  "variables": {
  },

  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[parameters('sites_name')]",
      "location": "East US",
      "kind": "app",
      "properties": {
        "siteConfig": {
          "appSettings": [
            {
              "name": "CONTRAST__API__API_KEY",
              "value": "<CONTRAST__API__API_KEY>",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "CONTRAST__API__SERVICE_KEY",
              "value": "<CONTRAST__API__SERVICE_KEY>",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "CONTRAST__API__URL",
              "value": "<CONTRAST__API__URL>",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "CONTRAST__API__USER_NAME",
              "value": "<CONTRAST__API__USER_NAME>",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING",
              "value": "1",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "CORECLR_PROFILER",
              "value": "{8B2CE134-0948-48CA-A4B2-80DDAD9F5791}",
              "slotSetting": false
            },
            {
              "name": "CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH_32",
              "value": "D:/home/SiteExtensions\\Contrast.NetCore.Azure.SiteExtension\\ContrastNetCoreAppService\\contrast\\runtimes\\win-x86\\native\\ContrastProfiler.dll",
              "slotSetting": false

            }
          ]
        }

      },

      "resources": [
        {
          "name": "Contrast.NetCore.Azure.SiteExtension",
          "type": "siteextensions",
          "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
          "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', parameters('sites_name'))]"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

In `Azure Portal` => `Create a resource` => search for `Template deployment (deploy using custom templates)` => click on `Create`

[image]

- Click on the template shown below
  [image]
- Copy paste the above given `ARM Template` ,click on Save.
  [image]
- The details provided in the template will be displayed in the `Instance details`
  [image]
- Provide the Subscription and Resource group details and click on `Review +create` to continue the steps.
  [image]
- Navigate to your Resource Group, you can see the App service has been created with the given name.

[image]

- In `Azure App Service` => Under `Development Tools` select `Extensions`, you can see the Installed `Contrast .NET Core Site Extension` .
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Many thank Harshitha! It's awesome.
I have finished setup on CI/CD that's can add an extension to the list web app:

[image]

[image]